# Django upload for processing

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to upload file to django server. The thing is I'm not trying to save in I just to open it and get data for processing. I looked through some of the examples here, but I couldn't find anything that answers this. I'm probably just not looking for a correct thing please help.

I don't want to use models, just a simple website with a upload button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Form:

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):

    file = forms.FileField()

    def process(self):
        file = self.cleaned_data.get('file')
        # do whatever you need here to process the file
        # e.g. data = file.read()
```

In your view, call `process()` on your form after the user uploads the file and the form is successfully validated.

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.process()
            return ...
```

Depending on the size of the file and your Django settings for [`FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#file-upload-handlers), the file is discarded immediately after the view is done processing if `MemoryFileUploadHandler` is used. The operating system will also eventually discard the file if `TemporaryFileUploadHandler` is used.